# How do you arrive at $\eta : \text{Hom}_{C'}(Y, Y') \to \text{Hom}_{C'}(LR(Y), Y')$ from $\eta : LR \to \text{id}_{C'}$?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors, representable-functor

On page 28 of "Categories and Sheaves" it says:

$$
\eta : L R \to \text{id}_{C'}
$$

is a functor but then they have in a commutative diagram right below that:

$$
\text{Hom}_{C'}(Y, Y') \xrightarrow{\eta_Y} \text{Hom}_{C'}(LR(Y), Y')
$$

How does that make sense?

Comment: do you mean it is a natural transformation between functors? because what you have written there looks an awful lot like a counit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the morphism $\eta^Y : LR(Y) \to Y$ and you apply the contravariant functor $\mathrm{Hom}_{C'}(-,Y')$. This yields the desired morphism
$$
\text{Hom}_{C'}(Y, Y') \xrightarrow{\eta_Y} \text{Hom}_{C'}(LR(Y), Y').
$$

Comment: Shouldn't we put a $*$ next to $\eta_Y$: $\eta_Y^*$ since taking the domain-changing hom functor results in composition with $\eta_Y$ on the right?

Comment: @RollupandsmokeAdjoint : I don't know the notations from your book, but I agree with you, we may write $\eta_Y := (\eta^Y)^*$, or write $\eta_Y :LR(Y) \to Y$ and $\eta_Y^* : \text{Hom}_{C'}(Y, Y') \to \text{Hom}_{C'}(LR(Y), Y')$.